# What is the best practice terminology for e-commerce documents and "static" reference documents?

Tags: terminology, e-commerce, labels

I am designing an eCommerce website where the user has an account with the company and buys their products on credit. The user then settles the invoices each month.

The website contains two document repositories - One contains all of the user's e-commerce documents (e.g. invoices, monthly statements, delivery notes). The other repository contains static documents (e.g. product brochures, fact sheets). These two repositories must be kept separate so I need to make sure they are clearly labelled.

What is the best practice terminology for each of these?

Is it "order docs" and "information docs"? (...no, a delivery doc is not an order doc)

Is it "dynamic docs" and "static docs"? (...no, this is jargon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for :

- e-commerce docs in "My account" (even if it already exist) with clear categories
- statics ones regrouped in something like "documentation" **AND** in each page/form/other element wich is in relation with the needed information. I mean if you talk about a certain product in a page, add the file in there.